# Selecting all columns with rounding

Tags: sql

How to select all columns in a SQL statement with rounding? considering all columns are numeric and integer.
Something like

SELECT round(*, 2)
FROM table_name

Or do I need to provide each and every column name?

Comment: What RDBMS?  I have not heard of one having that functionality, but it depends on the DB.

Comment: "*do I need to provide each and every column name*" - yes.

Comment: you can see my updated answer.

Comment: @CDS: database is SQLite

Comment: okk. Then I accept this that there is no such functionality provided where I can select all columns with rounding without providing their name..

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this.

```
SELECT ROUND(column1, 2) as A,ROUND(column2, 2) as B,ROUND(column3, 2) as C FROM table_name.
```

You can also use following query if you want to modify permanent in database.

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = ROUND(column, 2)
```

Comment: He knows this as per the last sentence "Or do I need to provide each and every column name?"  That's not his question.

Answer (score 0):

You must mention all the columns'Names in MySql. The * won't work. So, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT round(name_columnA, 2) as name_columnA, 
       round(name_columnB, 2) as name_columnB, 
       ..., 
       round(name_columnN, 2) as name_columnN 
FROM table_name ;
```